# How to use Sweet Alert with Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

I'm using Laravel8. I'm currently deleting an event directly from my view.
But I want confirmation before the action, through Sweet Alert.
Below are my view, controller and routes.
Please,
How can I do this?

View
`

```
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Nome</th>
                <th scope="col">Participantes</th>
                <th scope="col">Ações</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($events as $event)
                <tr>
                    <input type="hidden" class="delete_val" value="{{ $event->id }}">
                    <td scropt="row">{{ $loop->index + 1 }}</td>
                    <td><a href="/events/{{ $event->id }}">{{ $event->title }}</a></td>
                    <td>{{ count($event->users) }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/events/edit/{{ $event->id }}" class="btn btn-info edit-btn"><ion-icon name="create-outline"></ion-icon> Editar</a>


                        @if(!count($event->users))
                            <form id="form" action="/events/{{ $event->id }}" method="POST">
                                @csrf
                                @method('DELETE')
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger delete-btn"  >
                                     <ion-icon name="trash-outline"></ion-icon> Deletar</button>
                            </form>
                        @else
                            <button  class="btn btn-primary"><ion-icon name="people-outline"></ion-icon> Participante(s)</button>
                        @endif
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Controller

```
 public function destroy($id) {
        Event::findOrFail($id)->delete();
        
        return redirect('/dashboard')->with('msg', 'Evento excluído com sucesso!');

    }
```

Route

```
Route::delete('/events/{id}', [EventController::class, 'destroy'])->middleware('auth');
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a Sweet Alert confirmation before deleting an event in your Laravel 8 application, you can use a JavaScript library like Sweet Alert 2. Here are the steps you can follow:
Install Sweet Alert 2 using npm. Run the following command in your terminal:
npm install sweetalert2Include the Sweet Alert CSS and JavaScript files in your Laravel application. You can add the following lines to the head section of your main.blade.php layout file:

```
<!-- Sweet Alert -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10.16.6/dist/sweetalert2.min.css">
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10.16.6/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>Update your view file to add a Sweet Alert confirmation before deleting an event. Replace the form tag in your view with the following code:
view

<form id="delete-form-{{ $event->id }}" action="{{ route('events.destroy', $event->id) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-btn" onclick="deleteEvent({{ $event->id }})">
        <ion-icon name="trash-outline"></ion-icon> Deletar
    </button>
</form>This code adds a deleteEvent() function to the delete button's onclick attribute. The function displays a Sweet Alert confirmation dialog with two buttons - "Confirm" and "Cancel". If the user clicks "Confirm", the form is submitted to the server to delete the event. Otherwise, the dialog is closed, and nothing happens.
Add the following JavaScript code to your view or a separate file to define the deleteEvent() function:
<script>
    function deleteEvent(id) {
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Você tem certeza?',
            text: 'Esta ação não pode ser desfeita!',
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#d33',
            cancelButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            confirmButtonText: 'Confirmar',
            cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                document.getElementById('delete-form-' + id).submit();
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

This code defines the deleteEvent() function to display the Sweet Alert confirmation dialog. If the user clicks "Confirm", the function submits the form to the server to delete the event.
Update your routes file to use named routes. Add the following line to your routes file:
web.php
Route::delete('/events/{id}', [EventController::class, 'destroy'])->middleware('auth')->name('events.destroy');This line defines a named route for the events.destroy action, which can be used to generate the URL for the form's action attribute.
With these changes, you should now be able to see a Sweet Alert confirmation dialog when you click the "Deletar" button for an event. If you confirm the action, the event will be deleted from the database, and you will be redirected to the dashboard with a success message.

Hope this helps